# Using custom RoutedEvent in WPF causes TargetInvocationException

Tags: wpf, routed-events

I am trying out custom routed events, but I get a TargetInvocationException when compiling with an Attached Event Handler.

I have the following code inside custom control `EventRaiserControl`:

```
public static readonly RoutedEvent KickedEvent = EventManager.RegisterRoutedEvent("KickedEvent", RoutingStrategy.Bubble, typeof(RoutedEventHandler), typeof(EventRaiserControl));

public event RoutedEventHandler Kicked
{
    add
    { this.AddHandler(KickedEvent, value); }

    remove
    { this.RemoveHandler(KickedEvent, value); }
}

private void btn1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    RaiseEvent(new RoutedEventArgs(KickedEvent));
}
```

I then have the following XAML in my main window:

```
<StackPanel local:EventRaiserControl.Kicked="StackPanel_Kicked">
    <local:EventRaiserControl Kicked="EventRaiserControl_Kicked"/>
</StackPanel>
```

With the following handlers in the MainWindow code behind:

```
private void StackPanel_Kicked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Caught Kicked Event at Panel level.");
}

private void EventRaiserControl_Kicked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Caught Kicked Event at Control level.");
}
```

My code works fine with this handler:

```
<local:EventRaiserControl Kicked="EventRaiserControl_Kicked"/>
```

But fails with `TargetInvocationException` the moment I add the attached handler:

```
<StackPanel local:EventRaiserControl.Kicked="StackPanel_Kicked">
```

Can somebody help? What am I missing / misusing?

Many thanks

Comment: Is the `InnerException` of the `TargetInvocationException` set? Typically the `TargetInvocationException` wraps the real problem.

Comment: My apologies, @CodeNaked, you are ofcourse right. The `InnerException` is "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first I was surprised why it is, but I saw the reason after coding as your code. Just change

```
EventManager.RegisterRoutedEvent("KickedEvent"....
```

to

```
EventManager.RegisterRoutedEvent("Kicked"....
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, that was exactly it. I often struggle to debug these kind of WPF errors - the code often compiles, and the runtime error is seldom informative to me. Did you spot the error jsut by looking at the code, or did the runtime error somehow guide you to it?

Comment: Oh, I don't have the better way than just checking exception messages. Sorry for not giving the good idea. This was also very tricky for me.